# render collections seperately with defined output?

Tags: rendering

I would like to set up a blender file with, let´s say, 80 collections (collection01, collection02 ...). Is it possible to render each collection seperately and automated, without switching them per hand on and off? (In maya render layers you could make the renderer in the command line to render each layer seperately ...)

Also, it would be nice to get images in a defined folder that are named according to the rendered collection (collect_01.png, collect_02.png ...)

Any ideas?